# Baidu map is messed up and tiles are Displaced in OL

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I'm using varsion@6.1.1 and I want to add Baidu map to it.

this is the function I created to return the source of the `Tile` :

```
new XYZ({
        projection: 'BD-MC',
        tileUrlFunction: baiduTileUrlFunction,
        tileGrid: baiduTileGrid,
        attributions: '&copy; <a href="http://map.baidu.com/">Baidu</a>',
      });
```

and this is the `baiduTileUrlFunction` :

```
const baiduTileUrlFunction = tileCoord => {
  const urlsLength = 5;
  const z = tileCoord[0];
  let x = tileCoord[1];
  let y = tileCoord[2];

  const hash = (x << z) + y;
  let index = hash % urlsLength;
  index = index < 0 ? index + urlsLength : index;

  if (x < 0) {
    x = `M${-x}`;
  }
  if (y < 0) {
    y = `M${-y}`;
  }
  return 'http://online{}.map.bdimg.com/onlinelabel/?qt=tile&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&styles=pl'
    .replace('{}', index)
    .replace('{x}', x)
    .replace('{y}', y)
    .replace('{z}', z);
};
```

and for the `TileGrid`:

```
const baiduTileGrid = new TileGrid({
  extent: transformExtent([-180, -74, 180, 74], 'EPSG:4326', 'BD-MC'),
  origin: [0, 0],
  minZoom: 3,
  resolutions: [
    262144, 131072, 65536, 32768, 16384,
    8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256,
    128,64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5,
  ],
});
```

but the result is not acceptable and the Tiles are messed up.
so what's your opinion about what caused this?

Comment: The y tile coordinate has changed in OpenLayers 6 (see tileUrlFunction in https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.0.0).  There are working Baidu examples in https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10374

Comment: @Mike Thanks, solved.

Answer (score 1):

It happened because of changes in version 6.0.0 of OpenLayers.

According to the documentation in [Github](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.0.0) in custom URL function you must change the value of `y` like this:

```
const baiduTileUrlFunction = tileCoord => {
  const urlsLength = 5;
  const z = tileCoord[0];
  let x = tileCoord[1];
  let y = tileCoord[2]; // <<-- the change is here

  const hash = (x << z) + y;
  let index = hash % urlsLength;
  index = index < 0 ? index + urlsLength : index;

  if (x < 0) {
    x = `M${-x}`;
  }
  if (y < 0) {
    y = `M${-y}`;
  }
  return 'http://online{}.map.bdimg.com/onlinelabel/?qt=tile&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&styles=pl'
    .replace('{}', index)
    .replace('{x}', x)
    .replace('{y}', y)
    .replace('{z}', z);
};
```

it's working properly now.